# How to set a redirect for a moved file (Not Folder) on IIS

Tags: http, iis, redirect

I have a file lets call it page.html, which I moved to a folder say folder/page.html. Now my problem is that Google seems to still be crawling for page.html which obviously causes a 404 error. I am aware that I need to do a 301 permanent redirect so any request to page.html is redirected to folder/page.html but I dont know how to do this on IIS. IIS currently seems to only support setting up redirect for folders not files. Please can anyone tell me how I can achieve this. Hope my question is clear.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has a good howto on setting up redirects which should get you started.  At the bottom of the page is directions on a file redirect:

http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/iis7-redirect-windows-server-2008

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this, I now see that I have to switch to content view to see the files. However, in their case they still had oldfile.html while in my case I dont have that file. Does this mean I have to have to copies of the same file and apply redirect to one? Is this the only solution? Thanks again

Comment: I've never needed to do it another way but I believe you can use the URL Rewrite module for IIS (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) and then setup redirects in the web.config file's <system.webServer> area.  Good luck.